# EC2 load balancer and VPC

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have set up an EC2 instance along with an application load balancer. This will be used as a web server for a react application and api. I have certified the domains via AWS certification manager.

Now my only issue with this configuration is that I would like the application to be open to the world, but not the api. Both the application and the api are hosted on the same ubuntu server with nginx.

After looking though, the configuration manager for VPC, I noticed under security I can change the inbound and outbound rules further under network ACL.

Couldn’t I add a rule TCP and UDP that would deny all ip addressed from accessing port 3030 on my ubuntu server and add a second rule to except to the host IP address?

**Domain(‘s)**:

- *.myexample.ca
- [www.myexample.ca](http://www.myexample.ca) – hosted on port 3000
- api.myexmaple.ca - hosted on port 3030

**EC2 instance**

- Name: myexample
- Elastic IP: 123.123.123.123

**Application load balancer**

- DNS: myexample.useast.elb.amazonaws.com
- Target: myexample
- VPC: default

**Route 53** – Hosted Zone

- Record Type ‘A’:

  - Name:
  - Value: myexample.useast.elb.amazonaws.com
- Record Type ‘A’:

  - Name: api
  - Value: myexample.useast.elb.amazonaws.com
- Record Type ‘CNAME’:

  - Name: www
  - Value: myexample.ca

Comment: Did you to allow traffic for port 3000 from the Load Balancer's security group, and simply not allowing 3030 from that same security group (which should be the case by default)?